# Grub boot loader not working after installing win 10

Tags: windows, kali-linux, grub, boot-loader

Last night i installed windows 10 on a new partition that I've created but after restarting the PC it seems like the grub boot loader is not working anymore also the win 10 boot loader is not detecting Kali Linux

Answer (score 0):

The windows bootloader can not boot linux partitions and when you install windows, its bootloader will overwrite the Master Boot Record (MBR) of the drive. The MBR tell the bios where/what to boot, if you want to continue to use grub you must reinstall it over the windows MBR. This can easily be done from any linux distros live cd that has grub installed. [Here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) is a guide on doing it with the ubuntu live cd.